# rsync: delete remote folder when its contains only excluded files

Tags: rsync

Imagine I have two folders, `A/`and `B`, with the following contents:

```
$ ls A/
main.tex
main.log
main.pdf

$ ls B/
project.tex
project.log
project.pdf
```

Suppose further that folder `B/` exists only on the remote side (`A/` exists on both sides). Running `rsync` with the `--delete` option deletes folder `B/` from the remote side. But now suppose I use `rsync` with `--exclude *.log`: then the file `B/project.log` would not be deleted, and thus I would get a message like:

`cannot delete non-empty directory: B`

One solution is of course to use `--delete-excluded` --- but this entails that file `A/main.log` will be deleted on sync. Is there a way around this? In other words, is there a way to make `rsync` delete a folder (that exists only) on the remote side, when its only contents are excluded files?

Thank you in advance for your help.

PS: this is not a merely "academic" example, this actually affects the way I keep things in sync between my desktop and laptop...

Comment: Are you syncing from the local system to the remote?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add that part.